# How can i identify which conditions are failing in a if statement with multiple & conditions to print error message in else

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to check which conditions are failing in above if statement so i can print error message according to it in else .. Thanks

if (mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.AccountId == sourceBillingLine.AccountId &
                                           mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.CostCenterId ==sourceBillingLine.CostCenterId &
                                          mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.ActivityCodeId==sourceBillingLine.ActivityCodeId 
&
                                                                  mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.PeriodFrequencyId ==                                                sourceBillingLine.PeriodFrequencyId 
&
                                               mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.UpliftRequired ==                                                sourceBillingLine.UpliftRequired
&
                                                mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.InflationIndexId ==                                               sourceBillingLine.InflationIndexId 
&
                                            mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.FinalRenewalStartDate ==                                                sourceBillingLine.FinalRenewalStartDate 
&
                                                mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.FinalRenewalEndDate==sourceBillingLine.FinalRenewalEndDate
&
                                               mergeBillingLine.TargetBillingLine.DocumentTypeId==sourceBillingLine.DocumentTypeId)

Comment: i want to check which conditions are failing in above if statement so i can print error message according to it in else .. Thanks

Comment: You could assign the individual Boolean expressions to a Boolean array and then go through this array and print error messages based on which conditions are false. For a simple check the cross sum of the array would probably have to be true based on a quick read of your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. 
You will need to use if() else if () constructs in order to target each condition individually.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is breaking your statement down and doing a painstaking debugging of you code.

The best approach for you would be to start off on the right foot by doing a nested if else flow and printing out a message like `print "success <name of comparison>"` or something along those lines to see which comparison is failing.

After that if you really need to have all those && and // in one statement you can package them all together, because you will know that the individual comparisons work. (But it's really messy-- and I would not recommend it)

Comment: Is there any other way rather than splinting it in if...else if ?

Comment: Sorry, no. You could write another piece of code that parses you current code and runs the individual pairs whenever it reaches the end of a conditional pair, but that would really just take longer than manually going through your own code.

Like @roadrunner66 said, you would parse and store each condition in its own array index, run through the array and see which ones are False or True.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your time :)